# Google Data studio filter Regex (other than negative lookahead)

Tags: regex, regex-group, looker-studio, regex-negation

The data source includes all link in test.com/blog/us & test.com/us/en
There is no negative lookahead in Google Data studio
[filter screen cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLFzH.png)

I try to write a regex that doesn't match (so I can include these links)

- test.com/blog/us/en (any link start with this)
- also anything after test.com/us/en

and matches (so I can exclude these links)

- test.com/blog/us/ca
- test.com/blog/us (any link with this pattern except the pattern "test.com/blog/us/en")

I think if negative lookahead works, it would be `/blog/us(?!/en).*`
now it doesn't work in data studio I wonder how should I approach this

Comment: why not set a filter to include `\/us\/en`?  are there entries that have /us/en that you want to exclude?

Comment: Did anything work for you? Try `/blog/us(?:[^/]...*|.[^e]..*|..[^n].*|.{0,2})$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cj5U53/2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```golang
/blog/us(?:[^/]...*|.[^e]..*|..[^n].*|.{0,2})$
```

See [this RE2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cj5U53/2).

- `/blog/us` - a literal `/blog/us` string
- `(?:[^/]...*|.[^e]..*|..[^n].*|.{0,2})` - one of the alternatives:

  - `[^/]...*` - any char other than `/` and then 2 or more chars
  - `|` - or
  - `.[^e]..*` - any 1 char, then a char other than `e`, and then one or more chars
  - `|` - or
  - `..[^n].*` - any two chars, a char other than `n` and then any zero or more chars
  - `|` - or
  - `.{0,2}`  - any zero, one or two chars
- `$` - end of string.